# Find logs from .exe run from powershell

Tags: windows, powershell

I have an app that runs unit tests on start up.  If I run from Visual Studio, I see that everything logs to the Output window but if I run the .exe from the command line, the `printf` statements show but nothing logged from unit tests shows up, I believe it's using `OutputDebugString`

Is there a way to force the output to the command line?  I cannot seem to find any logs in Event Viewer either.

Comment: Under normal circumstances, `OutputDebugString` output is visible only to an attached debugger. PowerShell can't debug (well, I suppose you could wrap the debugging APIs if you really wanted, but it'd be massively painful). You can use [DebugView](https://docs.microsoft.com/sysinternals/downloads/debugview) if you're content with just seeing the output and an interactive save. If you absolutely must have it as a text file controlled from within PowerShell, getting the app to use anything other than `OutputDebugString` would still be less painful than trying to make PowerShell capture that.

Comment: Thanks.  I'll look into `DebugView`.  I'm trying to setup a CI stage in windows so all I really need to do is archive the test results.

Comment: Another idea is to install and use `WinDbg` (or `cdb`, rather, but that's the same core). It's a bit of a primitive beast, but it is a debugger, and it is automatable from the command line, through the `-c` option to run a command at startup. A little script that uses `.logopen` to capture output and then just runs the whole thing with `g` should do it (you may need some more commands to disable any actual debugging, like breaking on unhandled exceptions or logging handled ones).

Comment: Thanks again!  I'm not familiar with the Windows ecosystem so I'm all ears when it comes to suggestions.